# Linking Social Account into Local Account on Azure AD B2C from authenticated user in .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Greeting,
I have a scenario, when the user that already login to my system and try to link their account into google social account (if their account is gmail) by clicking 1 button.
I have browsing about how to implement this, but nothing found.
Maybe anyone know how to doing this?

Note: I already setup the social account linking from login page and it's running well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of good samples [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples#account-linking).

Also [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-identities-and-linking-them-in-azure-ad-b2c-33b72fcbfd25) and [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/linking-a-federated-login-against-an-existing-azure-ad-b2c-local-account-ea2db2fc2252).

You have to use custom policies.